# Edit default applications to open KML file?

Tags: google-maps, default-applications

This is a more general question than simply handling KML files, but this is the issue I currently have.

I was looking for an application that could not only download maps for offline use (so I can turn off roaming and avoid paying for data access while travelling), but also display a list  of user-defined applications (created on a computer with eg. Google Maps).

[MapsWithMe Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapswithme.maps.pro&hl=en) is supposed to be able to open a KML file, but when opening the attachment in Gmail, I'm not given the choice of opening it with MapsWithMe: For some reason, it opens it with MoboPlayer, which handles audio/video files and obviously complains that it doesn't support KML fils. Google didn't help.

Does someone know how to reconfigure Android (4.2.1 on Galaxy Nexus) so that I'm prompted for which application to open KML files with?

Thank you.

Comment: To my knowledge, an app has to register for that -- so it's not simply a question of configuration. You might want to try some other apps which are able to handle KML files, e.g. [Locus Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=menion.android.locus). With some luck one of them is registering for this file type.

Comment: Thanks for the infos. Without rebooting the phone, at some point, MapsWithMe did show up in the list of apps when clicking on a KML file.

Comment: As it helped solving your issue, I summed up an answer you might want to accept (so other "searchers" can identify this question has a solution). Thanks fpr your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, an app has to register for that -- so it's not simply a question of configuration. You might want to try some other apps which are able to handle KML files, e.g. [Locus Maps](http://www.appbrain.com/app/menion.android.locus). If it registers itself for this file type, it then should appear in the selection, and you can make it the default app.

As it turned out, this was exactly what happened with [Maps With Me](http://www.appbrain.com/app/maps-with-me-pro-offline-maps/com.mapswithme.maps.pro), so that's one candidate working for KML files.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, apps register for a MIME type, not necessarily for a particular extension. If the email has the attachment marked as the wrong MIME type, then Android will show apps that handle the MIME type that the email claims it is. Perhaps the sender of this attachment needs to configure his email client to report the right MIME type for the file.

As a workaround, you could try saving/downloading the attachment to your phone and then opening it directly: that way, the phone will detect what type it is instead of trusting the email's claim.

Answer (score -1):

I found a workaround: Move the .kml file manually into the maps.me folder.

Comment: What maps.me folder is this? Is it on the SD card?